# How to disable GPU for Python program?

Tags: python, cuda, gpu

I want to disable GPU from Python program.

I tried but the program is still using GPU. I am using Dlib face recognition.

```
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this instead:

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

The docs recommend using an invalid index (-1) instead of trying to pass a blank value; setting this value to something blank is something that various people have come up with on their own but doesn't always seem to work. Source: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars

Comment: And what happens if you explicitly set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES from the commandline instead of via os.environ?

Comment: Still using GPU.

Comment: There must be a way to completely disable/hide/remove GPU?

Comment: For me, using `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""` before actual code execution seems to work almost every time

Comment: You can add these lines in your code to completely disable GPU
: `os.system("export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=\"\"")`